# How to insert std::vector or array to a std::forward_list without using any loop?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stdvector, std, forward-list

```
forward_list<int> listOne;
forward_list<int> listTwo;
vector<int> arr = {2,4,3};
forward_list<int>::iterator it;
```

---

In the code mention above, I want to insert a `std::vector` in `listOne` and I tried using `insert_after` function.

---

```
it = listOne.begin();
listOne.insert_after(it,arr);
```

But it didn't work.

I want to know that, is there a way to add a `std::vector` or array in a `std::forward_list` without any loop ?

Comment: `listOne.insert_after(it, arr.begin(), arr.end());`

Comment: @康桓瑋 why use `it` if we are using `.begin() and .end()`

Comment: *"i want to insert a vector in `listOne`"* -- do you instead mean that you want to insert **the elements of** a vector into `listOne`? You cannot insert the vector itself, because the list contains `int`s, not `vector<int>`s.

Comment: @JaMiT no what i mean by inserting vector is inserting all the elements of the vector in a `listOne` without using any loop

Comment: @Dhruv I don't follow. I asked if you meant that you want to insert the elements of a vector into a list, and you countered with "no," you meant that you want to insert the elements of a vector into a list. How is what you meant different than what I asked? (Why "no" instead of "yes"?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `std::copy` with `std::front_inserter`

```
copy(arr.rbegin(), arr.rend(), front_inserter(listOne));
```

[Working demo](https://ideone.com/qApwyu)

Answer (score 5):

> I want to know that, is there a way to add a `std::vector` or `std::array` in a `std::forward_list` without any loop?

Since the question is more generic, I would like to give all the possible solutions using `std::forward_list` itself:

1. Using the [range constructor of the `std::forward_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list/forward_list)<sup>5</sup>

   ```
   std::vector<int> arr{ 1, 2, 4, 3 };
   std::forward_list<int> listOne{ arr.cbegin(), arr.cend() };
   ```
2. Using the [assignment `std::forward_list::operator=`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list/operator%3D)<sup>3</sup> (creates a temp  `std::initializer_list` from range passed)!

   ```
   std::vector<int> arr{ 1, 2, 4, 3 };
   std::forward_list<int> listOne = { arr.cbegin(), arr.cend() };
   ```
3. To replaces the contents of the forward_list, via  member [`std::forward_list::assign()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list/assign)

   ```
   std::vector<int> arr{ 1, 2, 4, 3 };
   std::forward_list <int> listOne{ 11, 22 };
   listOne.assign(arr.cbegin(), arr.cend());  // replaces the  { 11, 22 }
   ```
4. To inserts elements after the specified position in the forward list via the member [`std::forward_list::insert_after()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list/insert_after)

   ```
   std::vector<int> arr{ 1, 2, 4, 3 };
   std::forward_list <int> listOne{ 0 };
   // insert the arr after the first element
   listOne.insert_after(listOne.begin(), arr.cbegin(), arr.cend());
   ```

Here is a [demo of above all](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/oE1n5MaKv).

Answer (score 2):

If you need it on construction you can pass begin() and end() iterators to the forward_list constructor:

```
std::vector<int> vec{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
std::forward_list<int> list{vec.cbegin(), vec.cend()};
```